# ComboBox, How to give value

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to assign a value to My ComboBox with the name "tbYear", this value I want to assign comes from My API. I'm getting the value correctly, I just have to be able to realize this piece of code. I'm using UWP, C#.

My TreeView in file.xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="tbYear">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Year 1"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Year 2"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

My file.xaml.cs

```
private async void GetData
{
        srcResults = await apiclient.GetValues();
        tbYear.SelectedItem = srcResults.Year;
}
```

But i get no error but don't work

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you're using XAML, it's probably better to use data bindings to set the selectable values and get/set the values in the ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set SelectedValuePath="Content"

```
<ComboBox x:Name="tbYear" SelectedValuePath="Content">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Year 1"></ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Year 2"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

And then you would probably want to set SelectedValue, such as:

```
private async void GetData
{
        srcResults = await apiclient.GetValues();
        tbYear.SelectedValue = srcResults.Year;
}
```

I would suggest to use GetDataAsync() as name, make sure to return Task instead of void also.